# Wanted a List box or even a list in HTML with drag and drop,double click and button click between the lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have requirement of creating two list boxes with drag and drop from one to another. I have a button to add and remove for selecting and paste from one to another. I should also have the same funtionality even on a doubleclick of the item in listbox . I tried with select tag HTML  ...I am able to get double click and add/remove btn click. I tried with unorderd lists ul tag HTML ...... I am able to drag and drop and event get the double click. Now I need the solution with doubleclick, button click and drag and drop in one thing. Either select or ul anything is fine, but 3 functionalities should be achieved ..Thanks in advance

```js
 $(function() {
     $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      connectWith:".conn" 
     });
     $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
     $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
      connectWith:".conn" 
     });
     $( "#sortable1" ).disableSelection();
   });
 $('#add').click(function() {
     //return !$('#sortable li:selected').remove().appendTo('#sortable1');
  // $("#sortable1").trigger("dblclick");
    });
    $('#remove').click(function() {
     return !$('#sortable1 li:selected').remove().appendTo('#sortable');
    });
    $("#sortable1").on("dblclick", "li", function () {
     $(this).remove();
         $("#sortable").append("<li >"+$(this).text()+"</li>");
         //$("#sortable1").remove(this);
     });
    $("#sortable").on("dblclick", "li", function () {
     $(this).remove();
         $("#sortable1").append("<li >"+$(this).text()+"</li>");
        // $(this).remove();
     });
```

```css
.listTab{
width:75px;
}
#sortable,#sortable1{
 width:50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Disposition References</title>
<style type="text/css">
.listTab{
width:75px;
}
#sortable,#sortable1{
 width:50%;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display: inline-flex;">
<table>
<tr><td>
 <ul id="sortable" class="conn">
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 7</li>
</ul> 
</td>
<td><table><tr><td id='add'>&gt;&gt;</td></tr><tr><td id='remove'>&lt;&lt;</td></tr></table></td>
<td>
 <ul id="sortable1" class="conn">
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
  <li class="listTab" class="ui-state-default">Item 7</li>
</ul> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
  </html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/raawdhm6/   here is my fiddle for this one..

Comment: From the code snippet, it looks like you're almost done. Only the arrows in the middle need to be buttons. I'm not sure at which point you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MrLister.  I want to add the drag drop functionality on click of the arrow buttons in the middle.  ie., if i select an item in the first list and click on >> button, the selected item has to be moved to the right and vice versa.  But the problem is, I am not able to get the selected item